# PTIJ: Impressive traditional gesture to go with "Shalom" (like the "Wakanda forever" salute)

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every once in a while, as I go about my business in the secular world, a non-Jewish passerby [notices my kippa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/which-parts-of-the-head-should-be-covered-by-the-kippa) and approaches, then offers the greeting that is somewhat well-known in popular culture as the one Jews prefer: ["Shalom."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_greetings#Greetings_and_farewells) I appreciate this cross-cultural gesture, and I always [respond](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/778/shalom-alaichem-and-vice-versa) with my own cordial "Shalom," but I feel like something's missing.

I recently saw the movie [*Black Panther*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(film)), and noticed that when people from the nation of [Wakanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakanda) portrayed therein greet each other with the traditional "Wakanda forever!" they have a [really cool salute](https://www.cnet.com/news/black-panther-inspires-athletes-wakanda-forever-salute/) to go with it. That made me think that there must be a really cool gesture in Jewish tradition that goes with the "Shalom" greeting, that I just don't know about yet.

This gap in my knowledge makes me sad. Here I am, going around visibly representing an ancient body of tradition, and when someone notices and engages in our traditional greeting, I don't know the impressive ancient move to make when responding, so that my greeter can leave the meeting satisfied that they've not only exchanged greetings with an authentic Jew, but that it was an awesome encounter with an ancient tribe.

So, what is the traditional gesture to make when extending the Shalom greeting? What details should one make sure to include so that it comes off as authentically awesome?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: TBH it would be really cool if we actually had such a thing. Maybe we should start one.

Comment: @DonielF The answer box is open!

Comment: well don't you know that the real jews were actually black so the wakanda salute is good enough

Comment: That's easy! A  confused look on your face as you suddenly look behind you, trying to figure out if someone is calling your name or you failed to recognize an acquaintance. I do it all the time.

Comment: @DonielF There already is one (mentioned by [Solomon Maimon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salomon_Maimon) in the beginning of his autobiography).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Make a scooping motion as you press your middle three fingers against your palm.**

(Your hand will end up making a sign-language letter Y.) As the verse reads:

> VeKamatz HaKohen min haMincha es AzkarasaH
>
> *The kohen shall fingerscoop the generous heretic, along with the azkara.*

- All Jews are kohanim, as the verse says:

> Mamleches Kohanim VeGoy Kadosh

- The Gemara explains that the finger-scoop is done with the three middle fingers against the palm.
- The non-Jew shouting "Shalom!" to you is a generous heretic
- "Azkara" means the name of G-d, and as we all know, "Shalom" is a name of G-d.

Therefore the verse reads:

> All Jews should do a three-finger scoop motion to the generous heretic, as they shout "Shalom!"

QED.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, G-d!

Comment: Be careful to use the *three* middle fingers. If it's just two of them, there [might be an issue with that](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16820/).

Answer (score 5):

The [Vulcan salute](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_salute) would be most accurate, here. It consists of a raised hand with the palm forward and the thumb extended, while the fingers are parted between the middle and ring finger.

Its origins are closely related, too. As Wikipedia teaches us:

> In his autobiography I Am Not Spock, Nimoy wrote that he based it on the Priestly Blessing performed by Jewish Kohanim with both hands, thumb to thumb in this same position, representing the Hebrew letter Shin (ש), which has three upward strokes similar to the position of the thumb and fingers in the gesture. The letter Shin here stands for El Shaddai, meaning "Almighty (God)", as well as for Shekinah and **Shalom**. Nimoy wrote that when he was a child, his grandfather took him to an Orthodox synagogue, where he saw the blessing performed and was impressed by it.

The best part is, you can try it right at the keyboard with [this](https://emojipedia.org/raised-hand-with-part-between-middle-and-ring-fingers/) emoji.

Comment: Careful to do this with only one hand. You know, not everyone can do this; shouldn’t it be something that all Jews are able to do?

Comment: @DonielF who can't do it?

Comment: @DoubleAA I mean, physically can’t do it, not halachically

Comment: @DonielF I'm not sure who physically can't do it. I have no problem and I'm not a Cohen.

Comment: @DanF I’m not a Kohen and I can do it just fine as well, but I know several people who can’t do it.

Comment: @Doniel Why only one hand?

Comment: @DoubleAA Gezeirah that they’ll put the two hands together. One that I just made up...apparently about eight hours ago.

Comment: I don’t know the Halacha, but I think, for the salute, one would be able to use the opposite hand to assist. @don

Comment: This would go well with doing your very best Leonard Nimoy impression as you say " And upon you ... Shalom."

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Shmuel mentioned the Vulcan Salute - a good option. But, I have heard that since that gesture came from Leonard Nimoy a"h, who claims that he saw the Cohanim use this gesture while they were blessing the people, and he wasn't supposed to look, it indicates that he may have disobeyed the halacha and used that disobedience to promote the idea on a famous TV series. Sounds like a case of "mitvah haba me'aveirah."

I'd suggest a better idea. Mork from Orc's "Nano nano" gesture, made famous by Robin Williams a"h

[image: Mork & Mindy showing the Nano Nano gesture]

It is similar to the Vulcan salute, but the hand is held horizontally, and is used most often as a handshake, but occasionally as a salute. The main difference is that the thumb is close to the hand.

It also helps to talk fast and with a slight falsetto when you greet people while using this gesture.(No copyright infringement intended. Found via Google Images.)

Comment: I think you omitted a letter; you probably meant to type "nano nano**o**", indicating one-billionth of a nanoo.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Very cute. I can't vouch for how he spelled things. I can probably bet that a huge percentage of our readers have no clue who Mork was, anyway.

Comment: You're probably right.  More's the pity.

Answer (score 1):

**Melikah.** Motion like you're holding a bird and trying to kill it with your thumb.

The explanation why is an exercise left for the reader.