# Is there a Jewish non-verbal greeting?

Tags: minhag

Some cultures have non-verbal greetings (e.g., https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/handshake-alternatives-gestures-around-world-trnd/index.html) and these are being recommended in lieu of a handshake due to the covid-19 pandemic.  Does Judaism have any such non-verbal greetings?

Comment: Air-handshake (like the rebbeim do)... A nod and a tip of the hat were also common when more Jews had hats.

Comment: a chai five? ;)

Comment: We designated one last Purim: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100803/2

Comment: Many Hassidic and Yeshivish do a type of a head nod. It's hard to describe of you've never seen it. Kind of tilted to the side a bit. Sometimes comes with a smile or a type of surprised expression or a combination of both.

Comment: @Harel13 Do you have a video of that type of air handshake?

Comment: @YehudaW I can't find anything at the moment. It's something that's usually done after tishes (on Shabbat) where there are so many people that not everyone can reach the rebbe to shake his hand, so the rebbe just does a handshake motion in the are several times around the room, and the crowd responds similarly.

Comment: A sideways head nod? That's a "cool teenage boy" thing in Ireland.

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed a Jewish non-verbal greeting mentioned by [Solomon Maimon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salomon_Maimon) in Chapter One of his autobiography in the 18th Century:

> Jews with their wagons comprised part of it, and whenever a Jew passed through our village (something that happened quite often), he had to stop at my grandfather's inn, where someone would come outside to greet him with a glass of brandy, **making the sign of *shalam* with one hand**, and giving him a glass with the other.
>
> (My emphasis)

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what was this "sign of shalam".

Comment: With 100% seriousness, we need to dig up this information and re-boot this meme.

Comment: @YehudaW I don’t know what it was. But from the way it’s written it sounds like something that a contemporaneous reader would be expected to be familiar with.